# How do I reference arrays with multiple columns?

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my code below. The first two values are in the first column of my array and I am pulling the values correctly. Value 3 is in the 8th column, but it is just pulling the same value as value one. Also, the map and function after it... I honestly do not know why, but without it, I do not return values, but objects, which is why it is still there. I am new to using arrays, before I had just been calling each value with .getRange("A1").getValue (as an example), but I was using it too many times making the script slow and often timed out. (I am calling many more values than in this example.

```
var otherSheet= SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Project Overview");

 var data = otherSheet.getRange("B3:I20").getValues().map(function(row){ return row[0];});


var value1 = data[1,1].valueOf();
var value2 = data[1,2].valueOf();
var value3 = data[8,1].valueOf();


sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
sheet.appendRow([value1, value2, value3]).sort(2);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not use map. Get values returns a two dimensional array that is addressed as data[r][c] . The indices are zero based therefore the first item whether R or C is zero. The indices below may need to be adjusted accordingly. in the range you have extracted below B3 would be the top left most item and would be addressed as data[0][0]. B4 would the data[1][0] and C5 would be data[2][1]

```
var otherSheet= SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Project Overview");

 var data = otherSheet.getRange("B3:I20").getValues();

var value1 = data[1][1]; // C4
var value2 = data[1][2]; // D4
var value3 = data[8][1]; // C11

sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
sheet.appendRow([value1, value2, value3]);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the syntax I did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the value 3 is in 8th column, you should get that value from var `value3 = data[8,1].valueOf();`

Also for sheet.appendRow(), you can simply add those three values to a single dimensional array and pass that array to the method as below:

```
var value[0] = data[1][1].valueOf();
var value[1] = data[1][2].valueOf();
var value[2] = data[1][8].valueOf();

sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
sheet.appendRow(value).sort(2);
```

Hope that helps! If this is not what you r looking for, please update your question.